# alternative to indexOf in Javascript

Tags: javascript, indexof

I have string as `this is test for alternative`. What I want to find is location of `for`. I know I could have done this using `alert(myString.indexOf("for"))`, however I don't want to use `indexOf`.

Any idea/ suggestion for alternative?

### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rCn3Q/)

Again, I need this done by **Javascript** only. No jQuery.. sadly :(

Comment: *"however I don't want to use `indexOf`."* ***Why not***? Without that information, the question is pretty strange.

Comment: Always include all relevant code and markup **in the question itself**, don't just link. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : I just wanted to know alternate way... that's it... any more questions for me?

Comment: @ Fahim: *"I just wanted to know alternate way"* Again, **why**? For what purpose? Is there any reason for needing an alternative? [From the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask): *"You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face"*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.search()?

"this is test for alternative".search("for")
>> 13
```

Comment: @FahimParkar: Note that `search` is not a direct replacement for `indexOf`. For example, `"10 * 5 = 50".indexOf("*")` is `3`, but `"10 * 5 = 50".search("*")` throws an error. `"Hi, my name is Joe.".indexOf(".")` is `18` but `"Hi, my name is Joe.".search(".")` is `0`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That is because `search` expects a regex argument. In your example, `"Hi, my name is Joe.".search("\\.")` yields the expected value of `18`.


To clarify, `.search`, expecting a RegEx, should not be directly fed a string (but it can be). So, the above expectation would normally be `"Hi, my name is Joe.".search(/\./)`

Comment: @Akiva: I know. The point is that it's not a direct replacement.

Answer (score 1):

You could code your own indexOf ? You loop on the source string and on each character you check if it could be your searched word.

An untested version to give you an idea:

```
function myIndexOf(myString, word) {
    var len = myString.length;
    var wordLen = word.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var j = 0;
        for(j = 0; j < wordLen; j++) {
            if(myString[i+j] != word[j]) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if(j == wordLen) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```